# map.root is not working in rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

map.root :controller => "main", :action => "index"

is not redirecting the main controller to home page to localhost:3000

any suggestions?

Comment: What are you getting at localhost:3000?

Comment: I'm getting the default home page(welcome...) for rails..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you deleted index.html?

Comment: NO..I have not deleted index.html..It's working with localhost:3000/main..when I use map.root, its not redirecting..
Thnx andrei...

Comment: If you don't delete `public/index.html` you'll never even get to the app (it wont look at your routes).

Answer (score 1):

you must delete `public/index.html`

Answer (score 0):

I found someone else who had had the same problem.  Turns out that Passenger is running in production mode whilst my app was in development mode.

I put Passenger into development mode by adding the following line to my Virtual Hosts file

RailsEnv = development

Restarted Apache and it all works!!

Phew!

Purvez